# WPF ObjectDataProvider error "The path is not valid"

Tags: c#, wpf

The full error goes like this:

**The path is not valid. Check the directory for the database. [ Path = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Externals**

I am doing the following.Created local database.To connect it via binding to a DataGrid I used ObjectDataProvider to be able to edit data in the designer, based on [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30905/WPF-DataGrid-Practical-Examples) tutorial.I created a folder called "Externals" on the top level of the Project tree.There reside the database.sdf and dataSet.xsd  files.Now , I have a UserControl in which I do this:

```
<UserControl xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TypeAppRelease.Sasmaster.Data"
         x:Class="TypeAppRelease.controls.AdminPageControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 

         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="700" d:DesignWidth="900" >


    <UserControl.Resources>

    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="AlphaBetProvider"  ObjectType="{x:Type local:AlphaBetDataProvider}" />
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="AlphaBet" ObjectInstance="{StaticResource AlphaBetProvider}" MethodName="GetAlphaBet" />
    </UserControl.Resources>
```

Then later in the control I inject the data into DataGrid:

```
 <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="111"  DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource AlphaBet}}">

                <DataGrid Name="grdEmployee" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>

  </Grid>
```

Finally I have the custom Adapter class :

```
namespace TypeAppRelease.Sasmaster.Data
{
    class AlphaBetDataProvider
    {
     AlphaBetErrorTableTableAdapter adapter;
    _MyDatabase_1DataSet dataset;
    public AlphaBetDataProvider()
    {
        adapter = new AlphaBetErrorTableTableAdapter();
        dataset = new _MyDatabase_1DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(dataset.AlphaBetErrorTable);

    }
    public DataView GetAlphaBet()
    {
        return dataset.AlphaBetErrorTable.DefaultView;
    }
  }
}
```

Somehow while getting that error for this line :

```
     <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="AlphaBetProvider"  ObjectType="{x:Type local:AlphaBetDataProvider}" />
```

The project compiles and runs showing the data in the datagrid , but I can't edit the DatGrid as is done in the tutorial and I don't understand why the program is trying to access that path.

Comment: StackTrace? The app throws no error so I can see nothing in stack trace.

Comment: Then what is that error from?

Comment: At this line of code: <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="AlphaBetProvider"  ObjectType="{x:Type local:AlphaBetDataProvider}" />

Comment: It sounds like your `AlphaBetErrorTableTableAdapter` is incorrectly using a relative path.  Attach a second copy of VS to the designer and debug it.

Comment: Where can I config the Adapter?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved it by resetting the DB connection.